# Round-trip-safe escaping of strings in C#

Tags: c#, mono, escaping

I am confused by all the different escaping mechanisms for strings in C#.  What I want is an escaping/unescaping method that:

1)  Can be used on any string
2)  escape+unescape is guaranteed to return the initial string
3)  Replaces all punctuation with something else.  If that is too much to ask, then at least commas, braces, and @.  I am fine with spaces not being escaped.
4)  Is unlikely to ever change.

Does it exist?

EDIT:  This is for purposes of seriliazing and deserializing app-generated attributes.  So my object may or may not have values for Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, etc.  Simplifying a bit, the idea is to do something like the below.  Goal is to have the encoded collection be brief and more-or-less human-readable.

I am asking what methods would make sense to use for Escape and Unescape.

```
public abstract class GenericAttribute {
  const string key1 = "KEY1";  //It is fine to put some restrictions on the keys, i.e. no punctuation
  const string key2 = "KEY2";
  public abstract string Encode(); // NO RESTRICTIONS ON WHAT ENCODE MIGHT RETURN
  public static GenericAttribute FromKeyValuePair (string key, string value) {
    switch (key) {
      case key1: return new ConcreteAttribute1(value);
      case key2: return new ConcreteAttribute2(value);
        // etc.
    }
  }
}

public class AttributeCollection {
  Dictionary <string, GenericAttribute> Content {get;set;}
  public string Encode() {
    string r = "";
    bool first = true;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, GenericAttribute> pair in this.Content) {
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        r+=",";
      }
      r+=(pair.Key + "=" + Escape(pair.Value.Encode()));
    }
    return r;
  }

  public AttributeCollection(string encodedCollection) {
    // input string is the return value of the Encode method
    this.Content = new Dictionary<string, GenericAttribute>();
    string[] array = encodedCollection.Split(',');
    foreach(string component in array) {
      int equalsIndex = component.IndexOf('=');
      string key = component.Substring(0, equalsIndex);
      string value = component.Substring(equalsIndex+1);
      GenericAttribute attribute = GenericAttribute.FromKeyValuePair(key, Unescape(value));
      this.Content[key]=attribute;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In short, no. Escaping depends on the format that the string is stored in (c# code file, XML, HTML, JavaScript, etc.), so there is no one animal that can escape/unescape for every format. Sometimes a string can be escaped into multiple formats, but only you will know which escaping is applied, so only you can unescape everything in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your asking, but I believe your intent is for the escaped character to be included, even with the escape.

```
var content = @"\'Hello";
Console.WriteLine(content);

// Output:
\'Hello
```

By utilizing the `@` it will include said escaping, making it apart of your `string`.  That is for the server-side with C#, to account for other languages and escape formats only you would know that.

You can find some great information on C# escaping here:

- [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode`.  I think that will encode and decode all the things you want.
See the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpServerUtility_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and here is a description of the mapping on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).